# How to get a return value from a js executing using browser.executeScript in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to get a value back from execute script function and match it with the expect method.
as isSelected doesn't work on many checkboxes that are used in app, I have to go this way.
Here is my code, and I really appreciate your help.

I have tried using isSelected with these kind of checkboxes but that doesnt work.
Below code gives me the following error.
Failed: Cannot read property 'getText' of null

```
exports.verifyRegularCheckboxChecked = function () {
  browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
    var special_list = $('div > div');
    var returnValue = 'itIsTrue';
    var label, label_children;
    special_list.filter(function(index, elem) {
      label = elem.children;
      label_children = $(label).children();
      label_children.filter(function(nestedIndex, nestedElem) {
        if(nestedElem.tagName === 'INPUT') {
          if(nestedElem.checked) {
            return returnValue;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }).then(function (returnValue) {
    expect(returnValue.getText()).toBe('itIsTrue');
  });
};
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox"> 
    <label> 
       <input class="ark-checkbox ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" 
             ng-model="block.properties.milestoneIsVariable.value" type="checkbox"> 
       <span aria-label="ark-checkbox"> ::before </span> use variable 
     </label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show the HTML code

Comment: Here's the HTML, but please note that the input tag is all greyed out when inspected so looks like hidden. That is why am not able to use locators like ng-model, would have been simple.
`<div class="form-group">
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input class="ark-checkbox ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-model="block.properties.milestoneIsVariable.value" type="checkbox">
<span aria-label="ark-checkbox">
::before
</span>
use variable
</label>
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work by modifying my code like this.

```
exports.verifyRegularCheckboxChecked = function () {
  var result = browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
    var returnValue = false;
    var special_list = $('div > div');
    var label, label_children;
    special_list.filter(function(index, elem) {
      label = elem.children;
      console.log('inner text is: ' + label.textContent);
      label_children = $(label).children();
      label_children.filter(function(nestedIndex, nestedElem) {
        if(nestedElem.tagName === 'INPUT') {
          if(nestedElem.checked) {
            returnValue = true;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    return returnValue;
    });
  result.then(function (value) {
    expect(value).toBeTruthy();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery's [filter(function)](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function), you need to return a boolean value.

```
exports.verifyRegularCheckboxChecked = function () {

  let result = browser.driver.executeScript(function() {

    let special_list = $('div > div');
    let label, label_children;

    let checkedList = special_list.filter(function(index, elem) {
      label = elem.children;
      label_children = $(label).children();

      return label_children.filter(function(nestedIndex, nestedElem) {
        return estedElem.tagName === 'INPUT' && nestedElem.checked;
      }).length > 0;

    });

    // return matched Dom element
    return checkedList.length > 0 && checkedList.get(0);        
  }); // end of executeScript

  expect(result.getText()).toBe('itIsTrue');
};
```

Actually, you can simplify your code as following:

```
exports.verifyRegularCheckboxChecked = function () {

  let result = browser.driver.executeScript(function() {

    return $('div > div').filter(function(){ 
      return $('input:checked', this).length > 0;
    })
    .get(0);

  });

  expect(result.getText()).toBe('itIsTrue');
};
```

Comment: As you can see in my comment above have pasted html. I am looking for a solution where I can pass the actual value of text of checkbox to the function, like `use variable` in above html and then verify that it is checked or not. Your above solutions return something like this if I just console.log(result)
`ManagedPromise {
  flow_: 
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_: 
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::22696',
        flow_: [Circular],

        tasks_: [Array],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_`